# Why can Reduce solve for Integers but not for Reals?

Tags: equation-solving

I'm showing as an image, since the question is generic. If we remove $m$ from the inequality we get both solutions. Why doesn't the first inequality work for both domains?

**Edit** here is the code per request:

```
Clear[m, n, c, d];  
c = (m == 1 && 
n >= 0 && ((-1 + 3^n m)/(-1 + 2^n m) - (3^n) /(2^
   n) ) > ((-1 + 3^(n + 1) m)/(-1 + 2^(n + 1) m) - (3^(n + 1)) /(
   2^(n + 1)) ));  
d = (n >= 
 0 && ((-1 + (3^n) )/(-1 + (2^n) ) - (3^n) /(2^
   n) ) > ((-1 + (3^(n + 1)) )/(-1 + (2^(n + 1)) ) - (
   3^(n + 1)) /(2^(n + 1)) ));  
Reduce[c, {n}, Integers]  
Reduce[c, {n}]  
Reduce[d, {n}, Integers]  
Reduce[d, {n}]
```

[image]

Comment: The default domain for `Reduce` is not `Reals`, it's `Complexes`. Try `Reduce[c, {n}, Reals]`.

Comment: @ChipHurst, I didn't know the default domain, however using `Reals` also doesn't work.

Comment: Fred, would you mind posting the code anyway? I figure things out by tinkering, and I'd really rather not have to retype your equations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear[m, n, c, d];

c = (m == 1 && 
    n >= 0 && ((-1 + 3^n m)/(-1 + 2^n m) - (3^n)/(2^n)) > ((-1 + 
          3^(n + 1) m)/(-1 + 
          2^(n + 1) m) - (3^(n + 1))/(2^(n + 1))));

d = (n >= 
     0 && ((-1 + (3^n))/(-1 + (2^n)) - (3^n)/(2^
          n)) > ((-1 + (3^(n + 1)))/(-1 + (2^(n + 1))) - (3^(n + 
            1))/(2^(n + 1))));

Reduce[c, {n}, Integers]
```

> Element[n, Integers] && m == 1 && n >= 1

```
Reduce[c // FullSimplify, {n}, Reals]
```

> m == 1 && n > 0

```
Reduce[d, {n}, Integers]
```

> Element[n, Integers] && n >= 1

```
Reduce[d, {n}, Reals]
```

> n > 0

Comment: +1, `FullSimplify` is just the ticket!

Comment: Any thoughts on *why* `FullSimplify` is needed here?  Shouldn't `Reduce` manage this by itself?  (+1 nevertheless)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I wondered that too. I usually use `FullSimplify` after the `Reduce` to use the code elsewhere.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - @FredKline - It has been my (albeit limited) experience that when you hit a limit of the capabilities of a function's algorithm that changing (e.g., simplifying) the input can sometimes assist the algorithm. I assume that the reason that the functions algorithms do not do this on their own is that the performance cost of `FullSimplify` can be very high and it is best left to the user to apply as needed.